# Trouble porting over python-2.7 curses to python-2.4

Tags: python, ncurses, curses, python-2.4

I wrote my python code at home for 2.7, but now I'm trying to fix it to run on 2.4 here at work.

The first is hline does not work for me. I have

```
stdscr.hline(0,0,'=',5)
```

but it only prints out one `=` sign.

Second is chgat does not work in

```
screen.chgat(0,0,-1,curses.color_pair(2)
```

as it returns `AttributeError: chgat`

Not sure how to disable cursors since

```
curses.curs_set(0)` doesn't work either.`enter code here`
```

I can't find any documentation on curses for python 2.4.3 so I'm having trouble porting this over.

Comment: I know it's not a actual solution, but consider porting not the code but the ancient software up to at _least_ 2.6... Anything below 2.6 is considered **dead** for real!

Comment: Also, which version of `curses` (e.g., `libncurses.so`) was your Python built against? If you have a really old library, or a partial emulation of ncurses against a different library (which used to be common on commercial Unixes), Python does the best it can to wrap it, but has some limitations.

Comment: Finally, `curses` used to be maintained as a separate package, `python-curses`, which you could install separately to get a later version than the one that came with your python (just like `sqlite3`). I don't know if that stopped before 2.4.3 or not, but from a quick search I can see that some linux distros have `python-curses-2.6` or similar packages (e.g., [this one](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/18246679/dir/opensuse/com/python-curses-2.6.5-3.3.1.i586.rpm.html)), which is a good sign.

Comment: We're using RHEL5, and I don't have control over package installs. It shows I'm using curses 2.2

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your precise question "documentation on curses for python 2.4.3" is:

http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.3/lib/module-curses.html